# What's the benefit of private var and getter and setter over a public var?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

I see this a fair bit in code examples...

```
private List<Car> cars;

public List<Car> Cars
   {
      get { return this.cars; }
      set { this.cars = value; }
   }
```

What's the benefit of that over just:

```
public List<Car> cars;
```

?

Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, you can use: `public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }`

Comment: You can add business logic to properties but for the above example where no logic is used you could use a simple public List<Car> Cars { get; set; } which will automatically generate the backing variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a property, a property allows you to control the set/get operations and perform other tasks when a value is set or get.

For example you could check if the cars list is null in the get and in case is null you can create and assign a new List to cars then return cars.

Comment: if you do that this could make for a nice race condition if accessed by multiple threads in parallel...

Comment: @Yahia: As would exposing a field.

Comment: yes absolutely... I was just commenting on the example for a `get`...

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of notable differences.

- Several binding APIs will only consider Properties
- Several serialization APIs will only consider Properties
- Breakpoints can't be set on fields but can be set on properties
- It's easier to version properties than fields

Comment: Breakpoints are difficult to set on auto-properties though.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth yes but you can always temporarily turn an auto-property into a full property for the purpose of debugging.  The same is not true for fields.

Comment: definitely, I was just commenting for completion.  I tend towards auto-properties / properties over public fields almost 100% of the time.  Just noting because breaking an auto-property out when you are in a none standard situation (production / live code etc) is problematic.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: It's impossible to set a breakpoint on accessing a field (from the field side, of course), so I'm not sure how that's a distinction.

Comment: @AdamRobinson didn't say it was a distinction between auto-properties and fields, it was a distinction between auto-properties and properties.  Auto-properties and properties are sometimes incorrectly seen as entirely synonymous, they aren't 100%.